# TypeScript: Convert type 'a | b' to 'a' based on typeof

Tags: typescript, casting, compiler-errors

I'm new to TypeScript and trying to understand how casting can be used. I am working with an API that defines a function similar to the following:

```
function foo(a: number): number | undefined;
```

I want to perform a function on the return value of this number to safely convert it to a number always, but I get an error:

```
function myFunc(bar: number | undefined): number {
  if (typeof bar === undefined) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return bar; // error ts(2322)
  }
}
```

Where `ts(2322)` expands to `Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

I feel like this is something that should be determinable at compile time. Clearly, we only go into the else if `typeof bar === number`, but trying that in this code snippet:

```
function myFunc(bar: number | undefined): number {
  if (typeof bar === number) { // error ts(2367)
    return bar;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

The error message is `This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"' and 'Requireable<number>' have no overlap.`

At this point I'm pretty lost on what's possible with casting in TypeScript. Is there a way to accomplish my goals? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `if (typeof bar === undefined) {` did you mean `if (typeof bar === "undefined") {`? typeof produces a string, so the code you provided will always go into the else.

Comment: Make that your answer! I hadn't looked closely enough into `typeof`, you're very correct. That solved my issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (typeof bar === undefined) {
```

The [typeof operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) produces a string, so what you should really be testing is:

```
if (typeof bar === "undefined") {
```

As you've got it, the `if` case will never be true, so the code always goes into the `else` block. Typescript thus deduces that the return statement can be reached with `bar` still undefined, which conflicts with the type you said you'd be returning.

Answer (score 0):

Nicholas gives the detailed explanation, but you could certainly implement your function simply as:

```
function myFunc(bar: number | undefined): number {
    return bar || 0;
}
```